# How to use a variable instead of table name?

Tags: php

This works fine:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM table_01 WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

but this gives an error:

```
$table = "table_01";
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM'.$table.'WHERE id = :id');
```

Comment: What is the *actual* SQL generated? Why would it result in an error? (Also, please read the error message as it will say exactly what is wrong.)

Comment: And post your error message too!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:-

```
$table = "table_01";
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id'); (adding space before and after table in your code)
```

OR

```
 $table = "table_01";
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM  $table WHERE id = :id"); (adding space before and after table and use double quotes  in your code)
```

Answer (score 7):

Add space before and after table name:

```
$table = "table_01";
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Add space after and before  table name variable

```
$table = "table_01";
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have a slightly dissenting position...DON'T. If that table name is coming from anywhere other than your own code you are opening yourself up to SQL injection.  Additionally, if your code is used by any developers other than yourself you are opening your application up to maintenance and security issues.

IF you don't use an ORM, for instance Doctorine or at the very least implement the Repository pattern where you explicitly control the queries which perform CRUD operations instead of relying upon a passed in parameter, you run a greater risk of opening up your application to external attack.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $table_name = 'your_table_name';
 $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE id = :id');
   $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
   $row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: why to try? some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You did not included spaces. Try this.

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, title, content FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id');
```